# Cual Id se debe usar, llave foránea o propiedad de navegación

Tags: asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

Supongamos que tengo los siguientes modelos y estan relacionados en mi base de datos, por lo tanto puedo utilizar propiedades de navegacion entre ellos:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; } // Foreign Key
    public User User { get; set; } // Nav Property
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; } 
}
```

Si por ejemplo quiero crear un `User` y asignarle la `id` del mismo al `Customer`, ¿debería hacerlo mediante la Foreign Key o la Nav Property?

Mi duda es, si hacer esto:

```
customer.UserId = user.UserId;
```

Sería lo mismo que hacer esto:

```
customer.User.UserId = user.UserId;
```

¿Cuál de ambos debería usar? ya que se me hace confuso tener dos `UserId` en el mismo objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La Nav property que comentas te permite acceder al objeto `User` desde `Customer`.

En este caso, lo que quieres es asignar a `Customer.UserId` el valor de `User.UserId`. Por lo que tu primera opción es la correcta.

En el segundo ejemplo estas asignando `User.UserId` a `User.UserId` de una manera más complicada.

Comment: Gracias por responder, entiendo lo que dices. Entonces, ¿siempre para asignar un `User` a un `Customer` debo crear el `User`, obtener su `Id` y almacenarlo en `Customer.UserId`? ¿y la Nav Property solo sirve para acceder a los datos ya insertados?

Comment: Correcto. `Customer.UserId` es una foreign key, por lo que vas a necesitar que esté creada en `User.UserId` previamente.